# mvn clean verify -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@tag1 or @tag2" works. mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1 or @tag2" does not

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-failsafe-plugin

For everyone in my project,
`mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke1 or @smoke2"` format works for running cucumber tests. However, for me I figured that only
`mvn clean verify -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@smoke1 or @smoke2"` works (double quotes wrapping the entire property instead of just the value). Tried searching for answers for weeks and could not find any. Would really appreciate anyone who can explain why or what I am doing wrong?

**Here are additional details:**

1. I am using MacOS Big Sur and the rest use Windows 10
2. We are all using OpenJDK 14.0.2, maven 3.8.1, cucumber 6.8.2, junit5, failsafe - 3.0.0-M3

Additionally, my failsafe configuration from pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>Run all scenarios in parallel</id>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                                    <threadCount>${forkCount}</threadCount>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/ScenarioRunner.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <properties>
                                        <property>
                                            <name>parallel</name>
                                            <value>methods</value>
                                        </property>
                                        <property>
                                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                                            <value>${forkCount}</value>
                                        </property>
                                    </properties>
                                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                                    <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                                <version>5.7.0</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```

Comment: You and your colleagues are using different terminal implementations and they may have different semantics when it comes to escaping strings.

Comment: And maybe https://scriptingosx.com/2019/05/on-smart-quotes-and-terminal/